# Problem with EmEditor command line saving file after search and replace

Tags: file, command-line-interface, savechanges, emeditor

I'm using command line to open a file and search for ", and then replace that with |. This converts the file from comma separated file to a pipe separated file. This all works fine.
When I use /sca to save and close, it doesn't work because after the search and replace the Cell Selection Mod (+) button is highlighted and there is a call out box pointing to the Cell Selection Mod (+) button with the text "Cell Selection Mode. Click this button to toggle the Cell Selection Mode.(Right-click this message to show options.)"
The presence of the call out box prevents the /sca from saving and closing the file.

I need a command line way to eliminate the call out.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the "Cell Selection Mode" message, then select "Do not show this message again." Close EmEditor and try the command again.

The configuration for this is located in Tools | Customize... | CSV -> "Show Balloon Tip on Cell Selection Button".